# VBScript ending process started by .bat file

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

I have a scenario setup where I need to test to see if the results of a .bat file execution returned results. The .bat file calls up another .exe and the .bat file has a CMD DOS window that outputs critical error info to that DOS box from the .exe. If the .exe does not start correctly, I am able to check the results in our SQL DB. I need to close the current .bat file and re-launch it.
This seems fairly simple, I can get the ProcessID using the WMI call. I can terminate the process with a Terminate() command. This works for any .exe I use for testing: notepad, calc, iexplorer, etc. When I run the VBScript to kill the .bat file, it says it terminates the PID (which it does, since I cannot see the PID anymore), however, the DOS box is still open and the .exe called from the .bat file is still running. If I click on the "X" on the DOS box or right-click on the title bar and select "Close", the DOS box and the .exe are both killed. How do I get this script to work correctly. The server is running Windows Server 2003 (some are x32 and others are x64). Any ideas? Here is a version of my code, there have been several revs:

```
If colFiles.Count = 0 Then
Wscript.Echo "The file does not exist on the remote computer."
Else
Wscript.Echo "The file exists on the remote computer."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
For Each objItem in colProcessList
If InStr(objItem.CommandLine, "r15_A.bat") Then
    Wscript.Echo "Batch file: " & objItem.CommandLine  & "  Process ID: " & objItem.ProcessID & "  Parent ID: " & objItem.ParentProcessID
    Call TerminateProcess(objItem.ParentProcessID)
    Call TerminateProcess(objItem.ProcessID)
End If
Next
dim shell
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.run BATDIR & BATFILE
'set shell=nothing
End If


Function TerminateProcess(PID)

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Handle = '" & PID & "'")
For Each objProcess in colProcesses
On Error Resume Next
return = objProcess.Terminate()
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Handle = '" & PID & "'")

If Error Then

TerminateProcess = FALSE
Else
TerminateProcess = TRUE
msgBox colProcesses.Count
End If
Next

End Function
```

I have even tried to use the SendKeys to send ALt-F4, X, C, etc. AppActivate does bring the correct DOS box to the front.

```
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.AppActivate "r15_A"
    'WshShell.SendKeys("+{F10}")
    WshShell.SendKeys("C")
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT--------------
Yes, I am going to have to kill the process that this .bat file calls. Only down side is this DOS box stays open. Annoying but I can live with it. In the end I wrote a script similar to my first one but only checks for the instance I want to kill by checking the CommandLine parameter: (The first bit of code with "-FAIL.txt" test to see if a FAIL file is present, if it is, then the rest of the scipts executes)

```
Set colFiles = objWMIService. _
ExecQuery("Select * From CIM_DataFile Where Name = 'S:\\servers\\Logs\\" & LOGFILE & "-FAIL.txt'")

If colFiles.Count = 0 Then
'Wscript.Echo "The file does not exist on the remote computer."
Else
'Wscript.Echo "The file exists on the remote computer."
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'AppStart.exe'")
For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    IF instr(objProcess.CommandLine, "robo05-A") > 0 THEN 
        'msgBox "Found text"
        objProcess.Terminate()
        'This part restarts the failed .bat file.
        wscript.sleep (200) 
        dim shell
        set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
        shell.run BATDIR & BATFILE
        'set shell=nothing
    ELSE
        'msgBox "Not found"
    END IF
Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem your having is the the executable that is being called from within your batch file is still running.  I tried to recreated your setup with a bat the just did a `ping -t %computername%`, and sure enough the vbscript killed the cmd.exe but not the ping (Please note the Parent PID was explorer.exe, so you probably don't want to attempt killing that).  Now I could easily kill ping.exe from task manager which then closed the window...but I only knew to do that because I knew what the bat was doing and what was left open. You could do a WMI search for the process that contains "ping.exe", grab the PID and then close that and that would basically be doing the same thing.  Of course in your situation "ping.exe" is probably not the same executable as mine.  If the exe changes every now and then then you could grab the commandline from your process find the parameter which contains the filepath to the r15_A.bat file, then use the filesystemobject to open this bat file, look for any executables which it calls which could possibly be still running and then kill those....but really that may be overkill for what your trying to accomplish.